# Vue.js cannot add style from method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to add some styles into html element from methods:

```
<div class="add-profile-img" v-bind:style="getBackgroundImg()">
```

The method is:

```
getBackgroundImg: function() {
return {   
    width: 180px; 
    height: 180px; 
    background-color: 'yellow';
    background-image:url(this.BASE_URL +'/uploads/noimg.gif');
    }
},
```

However, I get

```
Syntax Error:   Identifier directly after number (79:13)

  77 |      getBackgroundImg: function() {
  78 |          return {   
> 79 |          width: 180px; 
     |                    ^
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimension in pixels need to be in string format so the function return a valid javascript object:

```
return {   
    width: '180px', 
    height: '180px',
    'background-color': 'yellow',
    'background-image': `url(${this.BASE_URL}/uploads/noimg.gif)`
}
```

Comment: I still get: `Unexpected token, expected "," (79:17)`.

Comment: Well, now I get `Unexpected token, expected "," (81:21)` pointing at `background-image`'s dash.

Comment: both `background-color` and `background-image` should be quoted. Javascript variable name can't contain dash -

Comment: Right, but now I get ` Unexpected token, expected "," (82:24)` pointing at  ``url...`

Comment: Please check the answer you can't do `url(...)` in javascript. It's a css syntax. It has to be a string.

Comment: But that's the whole point of outsourcing the style into methods. I want to use `this.BASE_URL` in css without hard coding the value. How can I achieve it then?

Comment: You can use template literal to create the url dynamically. Notice the back ticks used for the `background-image`.

Comment: Well I used the backticks in the method. just copied your answer. But still get the error. What I'm missing here?

Comment: As I said: `Unexpected token, expected "," (82:23)` poiinting beluw `url(...`

Comment: I just copy and paste my answer into a node console, and got no error. There shouldn't be any syntax error so far.

Comment: I'm sorry I had an extra backtick hanging around. Your answer is correct. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

can I ask why would you want to do that? As far as I know if you bind a style, just create the object in the data object and do not forget to use the style sintax adapted for javascript. (Camelcase)

```
data(){
    return{
        yourStyleVariable: {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use `this.BASE_URL` without hard coding its value.  AFAIK I can not do that in `<style>` part of vue component. Hence the question.

Comment: why not using a computed property?